# Javascript behavior did not say that input was not defined

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When I was writing code to make placeholder and hide it when user writes, I made a mistake and used input that was not defined in the JavaScript file but it works perfectly:

```
var input4=document.getElementById("Message");
var place4=input4.placeholder;
input4.onfocus= function()
{
    // this is input 
    if(input.text!="")
        input4.placeholder="";
}
input4.onblur= function()
{
    input4.placeholder=place4;
}
```

then I write the same code and use my defined variable `input4` and it works like no difference:

```
var input4=document.getElementById("Message");
var place4=input4.placeholder;
input4.onfocus= function()
{
    // this what i forget to do,use input4 that i defined    
    if(input4.textContent!="")
        input4.placeholder="";
}
input4.onblur= function()
{
    input4.placeholder=place4;
}
```

My question is how did JavaScript know that `input` is input of user in my element `Message`?
This is small project: [enter link of project and see](https://jsfiddle.net/9qn27dux/)

PS: I used jsfiddle

Comment: I don't think the first version is really working like you think it is.

Comment: `placeholder`s already hide when the user types.

Comment: `input4.textContent` is always empty, because input elements don't have any text content. They have `.value`.

Comment: _"how did JavaScript know that input is input"_ More than likely you have an element with name/id of `input` (ie `name="input"`) in your document and the browser automatically adds elements with names to the global scope

Comment: it works and this what make me ask i can upload website if u ask

Comment: input4.textContent is has default value

Comment: i do not have any element of that name he does not exist at all in java-script file or html file so i completely fell lost when it works

Comment: `<input>` don't really have a `textContent`, `innerHTML`, or `innerText` values as they are not containers. They exist simply because they are inherited.  So they will always be empty `""` unless you explicitly set those values (which the browser will ignore)

Comment: i mean that i defined input4 as my stackholder text but input does not exist at all in java-script and i did make <input> that have class or id but  why does he know that input 4 change ....i make it to prevent stockholder from disappear until user write any thing

Comment: Well, please provide a re-producible example in this case. I make a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/MatrixTai/bgy5woux/, and input is always undefined. Besides, I cant open your project, try use some site like jsfiddle for explanation.

Comment: thanks for suggest this web site i upload my small page on it 
[project__](https://jsfiddle.net/9qn27dux/)

Comment: Your jsfiddle causes an undefined error as expected: _"Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined at HTMLTextAreaElement.input4.onfocus"_

Comment: so why does it works with me on same website "jsfiddle" i run it too

Comment: You get the error as soon as you focus the textarea, you wont get the error till then as it is only run at that point

Comment: i try to focus and it works and use privet chrome to test link again and it is works does this mean it works only on my lap, i upload it again and create an account 
so pls try again :[my project ](https://jsfiddle.net/Mohmed_Abo_AL_Kuar/fL28wbut/1/)

Comment: sorry i could not see error it is exist but we reach to my question why does it still work like right one like i make mistake and he correct it

Comment: Because the `placeholder` attribute is automatically used by the browser, for modern browsers there is no need to clear placeholder and reset. The browser will automatically make it appear when the input is empty and clear it as soon as user put in a value. So you could remove all of your javascript and the placeholders would still work correctly

Comment: oh i understand the answer ...this is right that placeholder have its event to remove it self when some one write ,so function"input4.onfocus" will not work because "input" is not defined so it make the same like the right function that not work if user did not write any thing

Comment: thanks i understand answer and when i post it i see yours u help me so mush ....can u pls post it as answer so if some one need to understand ,see your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `placeholder`attribute is automatically used by the browser, for modern browsers there is no need to clear placeholder and reset. The browser will automatically make it appear when the input is empty and clear it as soon as user put in a value. So you could remove all of your java-script and the placeholders would still work correctly – **answered by (Patrick Evans) in comment**

Answer (score 0):

Your script would fail if input was no defined, chances are that variable is defined somewhere in your code or a third party library you're using.

Try searching for it in your project files.

Comment: may be it is on library caz i preview all my code and try to find input by ctrl+f
and it is not exist in script

Comment: and i did not use any  library or it is default  library  and this does not explain why it still work if i make comment on it ...stackholder will 
disappear even if user focus on it ...i want to stop focus from work if user did not write any thing